# unattended-upgrade on specific day?

Tags: apt, upgrade, 22.04, unattended-upgrades, schedule

I have a few clustered servers which I want to upgrade with unattended upgrades - but on different days of the week. Since I can loose multiple nodes in the cluster I want to ensure that one runs unattended-upgrade on Monday, one on Wednesday and one on Friday.

Looking at unattended-upgrades I'm a bit confused when it comes to the scheduling. There are multiple `systemd-timers` in relation to apt:

```
$ systemctl list-timers | head -1; systemctl list-timers | grep -e apt -e update; systemctl list-timers | tail -3
NEXT                        LEFT           LAST                        PASSED       UNIT                           ACTIVATES
Fri 2023-12-08 12:09:06 CET 2h 10min left  Fri 2023-12-08 04:59:42 CET 4h 58min ago apt-daily.timer                apt-daily.service
Fri 2023-12-08 14:49:29 CET 4h 51min left  Thu 2023-12-07 14:49:29 CET 19h ago      update-notifier-download.timer update-notifier-download.service
Sat 2023-12-09 06:08:14 CET 20h left       Fri 2023-12-08 06:27:50 CET 3h 30min ago apt-daily-upgrade.timer        apt-daily-upgrade.service
Mon 2023-12-11 00:28:08 CET 2 days left    Fri 2023-12-08 04:10:29 CET 5h 47min ago update-notifier-motd.timer     update-notifier-motd.service

12 timers listed.
Pass --all to see loaded but inactive timers, too.
```

But none of them seem to trigger `unattended-upgrades`.

There is a `system.service` -  but it does not seem to have very rich scheduling capabilities:

```
$ systemctl status unattended-upgrades
● unattended-upgrades.service - Unattended Upgrades Shutdown
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/unattended-upgrades.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2023-11-17 14:40:05 CET; 2 weeks 6 days ago
       Docs: man:unattended-upgrade(8)
   Main PID: 866 (unattended-upgr)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 9389)
     Memory: 10.8M
        CPU: 83ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/unattended-upgrades.service
             └─866 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrade-shutdown --wait-for-signal

Nov 17 14:40:05 hostname systemd[1]: Started Unattended Upgrades Shutdown.
```

I guess I could [write my own](https://i.imgflip.com/88nok1.jpg) `timer` and have it trigger another invocation of `unattended-upgrades` - but that feels a bit like over engineering something someone has probably already solved better.

How do I spread the `unattended-upgrade` schedule over the week?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For most cluster admins, the default settings should ensure safe operation without any need for special tweaking.

Unattended upgrades automatically schedules random intervals for downloading and running. This is to avoid hammering the mirrors with millions of requests at clock-face intervals, but also means that machines in your cluster should *already* be offset by random amounts.

Also, Unattended upgrades is intended to work unobtrusively while your servers continue to operate normally.

Unattended upgrades should not be causing servers to drop out of your cluster, except in the rare case where a restart is required (kernel update) AND you have enabled apt to trigger the restart (default=disabled).

- Since that is a setting you changed, you can change it back.

---

You are also welcome to play with the timer. `apt-daily-upgrade.timer` is the trigger for unattended upgrades (`.timer`, not `.service`)

Don't edit the default timer (`/lib/systemd/system/apt-daily-upgrade.timer`), as your edits will be overwritten during the next package upgrade.

Instead, create an override file (`/etc/systemd/system/apt-daily-upgrade.timer`) to make your changes.

```
[Unit]
Description=Daily apt upgrade and clean activities
After=apt-daily.timer

[Timer]
OnCalendar=*-*-* 6:00    <------ Edit this timer setting
RandomizedDelaySec=60m   <------ Or change your randomization
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

Reference: [Acceptable OnCalendar format](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.time.html#Calendar%20Events)

If you do make changes to the timer or service, remember to circle back in 24-48 hours to ensure that unattended upgrades are really happening, and happening on your desired schedule. You have just disassembled and re-assembled a key safety and security component of your Ubuntu system, so checking for folly or mistakes is on you.